# How to properly used an `eval` expression into a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, eval

I have the following bash command related to the activation of conda's base enviroment:

`eval "$(/home/lucas/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"`

When I run it in the shell everything works fine, but when I try to run it inside a script it does nothing.

I have try all kind of things, mainly regarding quotation, but nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: You should really spend some time debugging this. You may figure it out yourself, and even if not, it'll help you ask the right question. (Hint: the problem has nothing to do with `eval`.)

Comment: Saddly I have spend the las three hours looking into it :(. Can you help me?

Comment: What does `/home/lucas/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook` output? You're attempting to evaluate that output as shell code. Is it valid?

Comment: When I run `eval "$(/home/lucas/miniconda3/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"` in my shell it effectively activates the conda base enviroment on it.

Comment: You have to `source` the script, you can't execute it. Other processes can't change your shell's environment, which is why `conda` has this `eval` command instead of an executable in the first place

Comment: Yes, I tried to `source` it, but wasn't able to activate the enviroment regardless.

Comment: What, exactly, did you try to source?

Comment: Ohh! With @chepner 's comment I realised what you were trying to tell me! Thank you all. I hate my self a little bit, hehe. The amount of time I wasted on this issue is ridiculous. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After everybody's comments I saw that the problem was that I had to source the script and not execute it.

Just to clarify the differences:

https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it